# 2 plot problems in R

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering why I have the following **2 problems** in my current plot (**see and run my R code below**), and how to fix these problems:

**Problem 1:** The plot ***doesn't appear in the center panel of my display window*** but it appears at the bottom leaving a big white space above it?

**Problem 2:** it seems the **tickmarks on the Y axis** are **not equally spaced?**

Here is **my R code:**

```
plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(.3333, 1000), log="y",ann=F, bty="n", axes=F)

axis(side=1, at = seq(0,1.5,.25),labels = c("0",".25",".5",".75","1","1.25","1.5"))
axis(side=2, at = c(0.33, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100),labels=c("1/3", "1", "3", "10", "30", "100"), las=1)
```

Comment: You are defining the range to go to 1000 but you are only labeling up to 100. That should explain some of the gap. You can more explicitly control margins with `par(mar=)` (see the `?par` help page).

Comment: Not a full answer, but regarding problem 2: the tick marks are spaced where you specify them. `at = c(0.33, 1, 3, 10, 30, 100)`, `diff(log(at))` show pretty close to equal spacing, but the gap between `log(3)` and `log(10)` is a little bigger than the others.

Comment: If you want truly equal spacing on the log scale, use `at = exp(seq(log(0.33), log(100), length.out = 6))`. Up to you if you want to liberally round in the labeling.

Comment: And, in the future, please ask one question at a time. I would have written an answer had the question just been problem 2. MrFlick may have done the same if it were just problem 1. Now we're caught in an awkward phase. (Though I welcome anyone who wants to elaborate on my comments and turn them into a full answer.)

Comment: Gregor, your second answer works great but even when I set the `ylim=c(0, 100)`, there is a big space above the plot, what can I do?